# uib-rating not getting color when append css using ng-class

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am using stars for ratings for which I used ui bootstrap rating directive and when I hover on those stars I need to change the color based on that.

HTML:

```
 <p class="col-xs-2">Ratings:</p>
   <uib-rating ng-model="rate"  max="max" read-only="isReadonly" on-hover="rating=value;hoveringOver(value)" ng-class="{{addColor}}" ng-click="viewPage||fnPutRating(rating)" on-leave="overStar = null" titles="['one','two','three']" aria-labelledby="default-rating"></uib-rating>
```

JS:

```
$scope.rate = 0;
    $scope.max = 5;
    $scope.isReadonly = false;
    $scope.hoveringOver = function(value) {
        debugger;
        $scope.lol = true;
        console.log(value);
        switch (value) {
            case 1:
                $scope.addColor = "red";

                break;
            case 2:

                $scope.addColor = "red";

                break;
            case 3:
                $scope.addColor = "green";
                break;
            case 4:
                $scope.addColor = "green";
                break;
            case 5:
                $scope.addColor = "gold";
                break;

        }
    };
```

CSS:

```
.red {
color: red;
}

.green {
color: green;
}

.gold {
    color: #FFD700;
}
```

Here is what i have tried

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/mBP4cMIKB06ARzU0MvvD?p=preview)

Comment: To what color do you want to change the stars?

Comment: @Roysh.
I need to change the color of the stars based on the values which i get on hover like if its (1,2)-red;(3,4)-green and (5)-gold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put like this

```
ng-class="addColor"
```

instead of

```
ng-class="{{addColor}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

try this CSS

```
    span.glyphicon:nth-child(1):hover,span.glyphicon:nth-child(2):hover {
    color:red;    
    }
    span.glyphicon:nth-child(3):hover,span.glyphicon:nth-child(4):hover {
    color:green;
    }
    span.glyphicon:nth-child(5):hover {
    color:gold;
    }
```